# Is it possible to ignore a beforeEach for a single test?

Tags: automation, nightwatch.js

I want Test Case 2 to do NOT call beaforeEach, but Test Case 1 and 3 should remain calling beforeEach, is it possible?

I am using NightWatch.js

```
module.exports = {

  before(browser) {
    // > this will get run only ONCE, before all the tests <
  },
  beforeEach(browser) {
    // > this will get run before every test case <
  }

  tags: ['your', 'tags', 'go', 'here'],
  'Test Case No.1': (browser) => {
     // > this test does something here <
  },
  'Test Case No.2': (browser) => {
     // > this test does something else here <
  },
  'Test Case No.3': (browser) => {
     // > this test does something else here <
  },

  afterEach(browser) {
    // > this will get run after every test case <
  },
  after(browser) {
    // > this will get run ONCE, after all tests have run <
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You cannot avoid calling hooks for specific tests but you can choose to skip the code inside them through some conditions. Below code will not execute code in before each hook when the test case 2 is running.

```
module.exports = {

  before(browser) {
    // > this will get run only ONCE, before all the tests <
  },
  beforeEach(browser) {
    if (browser.currentTest.name !== 'Test Case No.2') {
      // your code
    }
  }

  tags: ['your', 'tags', 'go', 'here'],
  'Test Case No.1': (browser) => {
    // > this test does something here <
  },
  'Test Case No.2': (browser) => {
    // > this test does something else here <
  },
  'Test Case No.3': (browser) => {
    // > this test does something else here <
  },

  afterEach(browser) {
    // > this will get run after every test case <
  },
  after(browser) {
    // > this will get run ONCE, after all tests have run <
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the structure of your test cases if you don't already have a lot of them.  The way I write my tests, the entire "file" is 1 test case that I name after the TC number in Jira (i.e. IW-xxxx.js), then each block within that TC is a step.  This will allow you to disable single test cases (even though you could just add !function(browser) to skip a step) and also allow you to have different hooks for each TC.  Here's what I'm talking about:

```
module.exports = {
   '@tags': ['nameOfTag'],

    before: function(browser){},

    beforeEach: function(browser){},

    after: function(browser){},

    afterEach: function(browser){},

    'Step 1': function(browser) {
         //code here for step 1
    },
    'Step 2': function(browser) {
        //code for step 2
    },
    'Make your verification/assertion': function(browser) {
        // assertion
    }
}
```